# Efficient equivalent to ifelse but with one option in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, comparison

```
# Two Ordered Vectors

sequenceA <- c(1, 2, NA, 4)
sequenceB <- c(4, 2, NA, 1) 

df <- data.frame(sequenceA, sequenceB)


sum(ifelse(!is.na(df[1,]), 888, 1) == ifelse(!is.na(df[2,]), 999, 1)) # Number of NA values that are in the same position
#? Number of non-NA values that are in the same position
```

Let's say I have two observations in a dataframe and I want to compare how similar they are. I want to know specifically two things: **how many missing values for specific variables they have in common**, and **how many non-missing values for specific variables they have in common**.

From what I see, neither *intersect*, *%in%* or *match* functions serve for this purpose as they do not consider the order of the values, only if they are found within the set.

I have come with a one-line solution to check the NA values, by replacing by a number (otherwise it just returns NA). Then I want to compare only the overlap among non-NA values, hence I would like to replace the NA for *sequenceA* with one placeholder value (e.g. "555") and the NA for *sequenceB* with one different placeholder value (e.g. "666").

I am looking for a one line solution to this: if there was an equivalent to *ifelse* without the *else* or a *do nothing* option, I can see it easily. Most of the similar questions that address this get the reply to just subset the vector and re-assign (**<-**) a value or use the **if(){}** commands, which make the solution excessively long (specially if it's something I find myself wanting to do usually). Am I missing an optimal good practice solution in R to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get missing values for specific variables they have in common, you can use

```
sum(is.na(df$sequenceA) & is.na(df$sequenceB))
#[1] 1
```

This can also be read as the number of `NA` values that are in same position.

---

To get how many non-missing values for specific variables they have in common

```
sum(!is.na(df$sequenceA) & !is.na(df$sequenceB))
#[1] 3
```

This can also be read as the number of non-`NA` values that are in same position.

---

To check for same value, we can do

```
sum(df$sequenceA == df$sequenceB, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: The second part is not what I am asking for though. It gives 3 and it should be 1, it is not considering the "same position".

Comment: @Kuku It is considering it, right? There are 3 rows with non-missing at same positions. Do you mean same value as well? `sum(df$sequenceA == df$sequenceB, na.rm = TRUE)` ?